# Looking for low footprint library for retrieving config values (typically key-value pairs) from PostgreSQL in Python 3.4 code

Tags: library, python, postgresql, configuration-management

I am reviewing ways to configure a suit of Python scripts on a server side system. I am currently using JSON to configure the Python scripts. The configuration files say things like how many threads to use, URLs to other servers etc. I love working with JSON files and python. Things are simple and intuitive; take for instance, how translation between JSON types and python are done - very nice - IMO. However, eventually our system will scale, as they often do. And I'd like the configuration to be controlled centralized in a database. We have chosen PostgreSQL as our DBS. You can assume we are going to use the latest stable PostgreSQL version.

Is there a python library or mechanism which in a simple way handles storing of configuration info on PostgreSQL? I could write a simple version myself, but I am assuming something better and more well thought out has been created before.

An alternative I am considering is to just store the JSON file in the table using the new JSON datatype of PostgreSQL, and using some constructed config name as the key.

Any suggestions?